# "acima"/"abaixo" e substantivos

Tags: gramática, classe-gramatical

Recentemente, eu disse "él dice la frase arriba" no Stack Exchange de espanhol e [fui informado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/la-frase-arriba-vs-la-frase-de-arriba) que o correto é "él dice la frase de arriba" porque "arriba" é sempre um advérbio e, assim sendo, apenas pode qualificar um verbo ou adjetivo e não um substantivo como "frase".

Até onde sei, "acima" também é sempre um advérbio em português, mas "ele disse a frase acima" é gramaticalmente correto e bastante usual. Por quê? A mesma pergunta vale para o advérbio "abaixo".

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. *Avoid answering questions in comments.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O espanhol e o português podem funcionar da mesma maneira:

- O apartamento de cima [que fica em cima do meu, por ex.]
- El piso de arriba

Só que em português, também se diz:
O apartamento acima [que fica em cima de meu, por ex.]

**Isso não se diz em espanhol com a palavra arriba.**

acima:

> A palavra “acima”, por ser um advérbio de lugar, **tem o poder de
>   modificar o verbo, os adjetivos, os substantivos** e até mesmo um
>   outro advérbio presente na frase, indicando as suas circunstâncias
>   específicas. Nessa situação, o termo “acima” indica uma posição.
>
> O termo acima pode aparecer sozinho em uma frase, ou acompanhado da
>   preposição “de”. Quando isso acontece, ela se transforma em uma
>   locução prepositiva, a “acima de”, que é usada na frase quando se
>   deseja fazer uma comparação.

Ou seja, acima, em casos como "a frase acima" é **um advérbio com valor de adjetivo:**
a frase [que fica] acima. O verbo implícito mostra a lógica do caso.

[acima tem o poder de modifica os substantivos](https://www.educamaisbrasil.com.br/enem/lingua-portuguesa/acima-ou-a-cima)